# Fade out, then direct to a new page

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have the follow code: The `wrapper` fades out, then takes the user to the URL. However, it only seems to fadeOut once. I assume this is because my browser has already cached/loaded the page, and is therefore quicker than to load.

Is it possible to make sure the window.location isn't called until the fadeOut has completed? My current code:

```
$('a').click(function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $('.wrapper').fadeOut(1000);
      window.location = this.href;

});
```

And I've tried a callback, but I assume the `this.href` has changed?

```
    $('a').click(function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        $('.wrapper').fadeOut(1000, function(){
                    window.location = this.href;
        });
    });
```

Any help would be appreciated.

http://jsfiddle.net/tmyie/em2Km/1/

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The `this` inside `window.location = this.href;` is no longer the anchor tag that was clicked but the function that was attached as the event handler.

try:

```
$('a').click(function (e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  var href = this.href
  $('.wrapper').fadeOut(1000, function(){
    window.location = href;
  });
});
```

Comment: Oh okay, that's clever. So I've captured the current state of `this` into a variable, that I could use elsewhere within the function?

Comment: Yes, you've captured the state of this on the click event when it refers to the anchor tag that was clicked. Then you have referenced that value inside the anonymous callback function where the value of this has changed but due to closures the variable that this was stored in before is still accessible.